# simplifying AND OR Boolean Expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing

My problem is turning a string that looks like this.

```
 "a OR (b AND c)"
into
  a OR bc
```

if the expression is like

```
"a AND (b OR c)"

 then gives

  ab OR ac
```

I can't able to design a correct set of loops using REGEX matching. The crux of the issue is that the code has to be completely general because I cannot assume how long the string pattern will be , nor exact places of OR AND in pattern   will be.

- **security OR ((internet OR online OR paperless) AND (bank*)) AND (mobile OR cell OR phone OR access) OR easy OR online WITHIN bank OR transaction OR mumbai OR delhi NEAR/10 agar OR (online OR internet) 
  AND (bank) OR not OR (apple) EXCLUDE (mongo)**

If i input like this ,it will solve this type of expression also.

Comment: Can the parentheses be nested?

Comment: yes it may be nested in some cases.

Comment: You can't use regex to parse expressions.  See https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-beyond-regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imo, you will need to use a parser here, e.g. `PLY`. You need to define all of your bricks and can then build a syntax tree with which you can do whatever you want.
An example could be:

```
import ply.lex as lex

# List of token names.   This is always required
tokens = (
    'VARIABLE',
    'WHITESPACE',
    'OR',
    'AND',
    'NOT',
    'PAR_OPEN',
    'PAR_CLOSE',
)

# Regular expression rules for simple tokens
t_VARIABLE      = r'\b[a-z]+\b'
t_WHITESPACE    = r'\s+'
t_OR            = r'\bOR\b'
t_AND           = r'\bAND\b'
t_NOT           = r'\bNOT\b'
t_PAR_OPEN      = r'\('
t_PAR_CLOSE     = r'\)'

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input("a OR (b AND c)")

while True:
    token = lexer.token()
    if not token:
        break
    else:
        print(token)
```

This would yield

```
LexToken(VARIABLE,'a',1,0)
LexToken(WHITESPACE,' ',1,1)
LexToken(OR,'OR',1,2)
LexToken(WHITESPACE,' ',1,4)
LexToken(PAR_OPEN,'(',1,5)
LexToken(VARIABLE,'b',1,6)
LexToken(WHITESPACE,' ',1,7)
LexToken(AND,'AND',1,8)
LexToken(WHITESPACE,' ',1,11)
LexToken(VARIABLE,'c',1,12)
LexToken(PAR_CLOSE,')',1,13)
```

It will even work with nested parentheses and you can then analyze smaller parts (e.g. from `PAR_OPEN` to `PAR_CLOSE`, etc.).

Comment: **Thanks** for answering my question ,this is what i am looking for. i learned new thing today(ply - lex or yacc). this will help me a lot for my future work.

Comment: I still can't get the output please can you suggest me any **tutorial** learn things and accomplish my output.

Comment: jan can you please create parser for sample problem `"a AND (b OR c)"

 then gives

  ab OR ac`    Thank you for helpin me.

Comment: @bipulkumar: I have posted another question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270555/grammar-construction-in-ply-recursion-allowed

Comment: thanks gilch , i will try to use this to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing makes it easy to define an expression parser for this kind of notation. Think of your AND, OR, etc. keywords like they were operators and your terms like "security", etc. as operands in an infix notation grammar, and you can use pyparsing's `infixNotation` grammar generator to define your parser:

```
sample = "security OR ((internet OR online OR paperless) AND (bank*)) AND (mobile OR cell OR phone OR access) OR easy OR online WITHIN bank OR transaction OR mumbai OR delhi NEAR/10 agar OR (online OR internet) AND (bank) OR not OR (apple) EXCLUDE (mongo)"

import pyparsing as pp
# enable packrat parsing, since this infix notation gets more complex than usual
pp.ParserElement.enablePackrat()

term = pp.Word(pp.alphas + '*')
SLASH = pp.Suppress('/')

AND = pp.Keyword("AND")
OR = pp.Keyword("OR")
WITHIN = pp.Keyword("WITHIN")
EXCLUDE = pp.Keyword("EXCLUDE")
NEAR_op = pp.Group(pp.Keyword("NEAR") + SLASH + pp.pyparsing_common.integer)
expr = pp.infixNotation(term,
                        [
                            (NEAR_op, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                            (WITHIN, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                            (AND, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                            (OR, 2, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                            (EXCLUDE, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                        ])

expr.parseString(sample).pprint()
```

Prints:

```
[[['security',
   'OR',
   [[[['internet', 'OR', ['online', 'OR', 'paperless']], 'AND', 'bank*'],
     'AND',
     ['mobile', 'OR', ['cell', 'OR', ['phone', 'OR', 'access']]]],
    'OR',
    ['easy',
     'OR',
     [['online', 'WITHIN', 'bank'],
      'OR',
      ['transaction',
       'OR',
       ['mumbai',
        'OR',
        [['delhi', ['NEAR', 10], 'agar'],
         'OR',
         [[['online', 'OR', 'internet'], 'AND', 'bank'],
          'OR',
          ['not', 'OR', 'apple']]]]]]]]],
  'EXCLUDE',
  'mongo']]
```

(Disclaimer: I am the author of pyparsing.)

GitHub Page: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Docs: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Install: `pip install pyparsing`

Comment: Can you provide me link, For pyparsing **infixNotation** grammar generator.

Comment: Links added to body of answer. There are several examples in the project examples directory that contain use of infixNotation, and there is a simple example included if you just type `help(pyparsing.infixNotation)` at the Python prompt after importing pyparsing.

Comment: i am just an intern ,show i don't have vast knowledge of python , sir can you please do some sample code for                                                                      `"a AND (b OR c)"

 then gives

  ab OR ac`                                                                                                                             i will figure out for rest of the example  , Thank you Paul for helping me .