# Grammar construction in ply - recursion allowed?

Tags: python, grammar, yacc, lex

This has maybe been asked before but I do not know what to search for, really. Suppose I have some string I'd like to build a parser with.

I have strings like `a OR b`, `b OR C` but also `a OR (b AND c)`. Now the nested parentheses cause trouble for me and I don't know how to construct the appropriate `p_*` functions. Is recursion allowed? If so, how?

---

This is what I have thus far:

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

# List of token names.   This is always required
tokens = (
    'VARIABLE',
    'OR',
    'AND',
    'PAR_OPEN',
    'PAR_CLOSE',
)

# Regular expression rules for simple tokens
t_ignore        = ' \t'
t_VARIABLE      = r'\b[a-z]+\b'
t_OR            = r'\bOR\b'
t_AND           = r'\bAND\b'
t_PAR_OPEN      = r'\('
t_PAR_CLOSE     = r'\)'

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()

def p_term(p):
    '''term : VARIABLE OR VARIABLE
            | VARIABLE AND VARIABLE
            | PAR_OPEN VARIABLE AND VARIABLE PAR_CLOSE'''

    if p[2] == 'AND':
        p[0] = "".join([p[1], p[3]])

    for idx, val in enumerate(p):
        print(idx, val)

def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error in input!")
    print(p)


parser = yacc.yacc()
res = parser.parse("(a AND b)")
print(res)
```

I'd also like to call it with e.g. `res = parser.parse("a OR (b AND c)")` but to no avail.

---

P.S.: This is based on [**another one's question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230139/simplifying-and-or-boolean-expression/54231472?noredirect=1#comment95361062_54231472), really.

Comment: Did you look at the [Ply calculator example](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html), which parses expressions with parentheses?

Comment: @rici: You mean the `p_expression_binop` function? But how to transform this to my problem (honestly, I'm really not into grammars)

Comment: An operator is an operator, whether you spell it `*`, `+` or `and`. A grammar abstracts away semantics leaving only syntax. So there is no fundamental difference between arithmetic expressions and your boolean algebra.

Comment: @rici: I haven't looked at it this way yet but you are absolutely right. Will check the example again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @rici: I might not get some basic stuff, really but why do the following rules do not work? I keep getting syntax errors for `(` and `)`, [see the code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/9Dezn2sj)

Comment: You are saying that an expression is either a term or a parenthesized term, and a term is two variables combined with an operator. But you want to be able to parse something like `a AND (b OR c)`, which is not either of those forms; the second argument to `AND` is not a variable. If you look at the example grammar fir arithmetic expressions, you will see that it is quite different.

Comment: @rici: See, the point is I thought this would have been exactly what I've been doing.

Comment: grammars are read literally. If you say, "VARIABLE AND VARIABLE", that's what it means: **VARIABLE** and **VARIABLE**. `VARIABLE` is a variable, right? Not a parenthesized expression.

Comment: If you look at the grammar in @Austin's answer, it says `term: term * factor`, also with `term: factor`  and `factor: ( expression )`. So a term can be a factor can be a parenthesized expression. and therefore a term can be a product including a parenthesized expression (on either side). (Unlike your grammar, that grammar is recursive.)

Comment: @rici: I understand that and I appreciate your continued help. But even if I define it like so ([see here](https://pastebin.com/6FVVYgJY)) I get syntax errors. I think I'll give it up and grab some compiler book, here.

Comment: Reading a bit about grammars wouldn't hurt. But why don't you try using literally the grammar in Austin's answer, only substituting `+` with `OR`  and `*` with `AND` (and getting rid of `-` and `/`)? That was my original point about a grammar abstracting away from semantics. (The choice of substitutions is driven by the idea that `AND` binds more tightly than `OR`, so `a AND b OR C` means `(a AND b) OR C` and `a OR b AND C` means `a OR (b AND c)`. If that's not clear to you, look carefully at the grammar, interpreting it literally.

Comment: @rici: Just wanted to let you know that it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses in an expression is quite common. I will first refer you to part 5 of [the PLY documentation](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn22) which provides an example of nested expression parsing. Yes, recursion is the answer.

There are several phrases that are used to mean the "smallest element of an expression." You might see "atom" or "term" (short for 'terminal') or "primary-expression".

When dealing with parenthetical sub-expressions, this is generally the approach to take. Write a grammar rule that unifies the various low-level things (for example, literal numbers and variable names) and add the sub-expression at that point.

In this example, from the PLY docs, `expression` is the highest-level thing, and supports addition and subtraction. The next level down is `term` which supports multiplication and division. The lowest-level thing is the `factor`, which doesn't support any operations, but does unify `NUMBER` and parenthetical sub-expressions. A factor could be `7` but it could also be `(7 + 2 * 3)`.

```
 expression : expression + term
            | expression - term
            | term

 term       : term * factor
            | term / factor
            | factor

 factor     : NUMBER
            | ( expression )
```

Comment: Thank you, will try to transform it to my problem.